# Nav Bar Wont Center Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav bar that I want centered below the title. I am missing something here, I want it to resize correctly, and remain centered the entire way.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="portfolio-head">PORTFOLIO</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <div class="portfolio-nav-holder col-md-6">
              <ul class="portfolio-nav">
                <li><a>Featured</a></li>
                <li><a>Websites</a></li>
                <li><a>Logos</a></li>
                <li><a>Graphics</a></li>
                <li><a>Photography</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Jiroscopes/e9L77ftn/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `float` from the links and make the `li`'s `inline-block`, then `text-align: center` on the parent (that you already have) will center everything.

There is also a default left padding on `ul`, so add `padding: 0` to `.portfolio-nav` for it to be truly centered.

And instead of adding a right margin to all of the `a`'s in the nav, only add it between 2 `a`'s, with `.portfolio-nav li:not(:last-child) a { margin-right: 15px; }`

```css
.portfolio-head {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-nav-holder {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-nav {
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.portfolio-nav li:not(:last-child) a {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.portfolio-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="portfolio-head">PORTFOLIO</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <div class="portfolio-nav-holder">
      <ul class="portfolio-nav">
        <li><a>Featured</a></li>
        <li><a>Websites</a></li>
        <li><a>Logos</a></li>
        <li><a>Graphics</a></li>
        <li><a>Photography</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfect, however the Col-md-6 had to be changed to col-md-12. Thanks!

Comment: @Jiroscopes ah yeah missed that, though do you even need `.col-md-12` there? It's already in a column. I just removed `.col-md-6` and looks ok. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the columns to only use half the size and then center the column

CSS

```
.col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 text-center col-centered">
          <ul class="portfolio-nav">
            <li><a>Featured</a></li>
            <li><a>Websites</a></li>
            <li><a>Logos</a></li>
            <li><a>Graphics</a></li>
            <li><a>Photography</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide width to the `.portfolio-nav-holder` to make it center align

```
.portfolio-nav-holder{
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
   width: 450px;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/1y5zcwus/2)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Float Property fr0m Nav link :

```
.portfolio-nav a{float:none}
```

Use Display Inline Property in you Nav List Items.

```
 .portfolio-nav li{ display:inline-block}
```